# Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2 for ServerName

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to launch a web server on my EC2 Amazon Linux instance via docker,
I'm flowinng this  [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html)  and this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y apache2

# Install apache and write hello world message
RUN echo "Hello World!" > /var/www/index.html

# Configure apache
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2", "-D",  "FOREGROUND"]
```

The problème that, after runing my "test" image `$ docker run -p 80:80 test`

the following error is triggered:

> apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified
>   domain name, using 172.17.0.2 for ServerName

Why 172.17.0.2, my public ip adress is 34.244.33.171, it's weird!
Even after visiting the web server via my public ip adress, nothing seems work!
I  think the problem is with 172.17.0.2, because docker use 172.17.0.1/16 as the default bridge network. 

I will be so grateful if someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been solved:

1- Firstable, we need to edit security group on amazon web service to enable 80 biding.
2- Second, the docker run command line should look like this: `docker run -d -p "0.0.0.0:80:80" -h "default" --name="default" -it test` 
`-h` for the hostname, `-it` to  specify our image, and if we need to assign a name to the container we just use `--name` and `-d` is to run container in background and print container ID.
"`0.0.0.0`" to give access to all ip address of the machine: so 127.0.0.1 and public IP will be exposed.

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck here too! Then I realized that right under the step where the tutorial tells you to run `docker run -p 80:80 hello-world` it says the following:

> Output from the Apache web server is displayed in the terminal window. **You can ignore the *"Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name"* message.** (emphasis added)

The tutorial then goes on to say this:

> If you are using an EC2 instance, this is the Public DNS value for the server, which is the same address you use to connect to the instance with SSH. Make sure that the security group for your instance allows inbound traffic on port 80.

You really should be able to your public IP and see the instance running. Is `34.244.33.171` your public DNS value? If you're not sure, [here's](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#concepts-public-addresses) some documentation that will help.

Comment: Thank for replaying.
Yes i'm sure, and 80 is up, i think the problem is with 172.17.0.2, because docker use 172.17.0.1/16 as the default bridge network. and it be changed to the public adress, anyway take alook here https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#the-default-bridge-network

Comment: That would make sense I think. Have you tried the tutorial using localhost? I'd be curious to see if a similar thing happened when you launched from your own machine

Comment: Bro localhost does not make sense, i'm not working on my local machine to use localhost, i'm working on my distance aws machine. I'm serching how to configure my network.. i will back

Comment: You're right, localhost wouldn't make sense if we were talking about doing the tutorial on your EC2 instance. I was merely suggesting that you could try to go through the tutorial on your local machine and see if you run into the same errors.

Comment: the problem has been solved, take a look to the solution :)

Comment: Nice! Way to figure that out. That seems weird that Amazon wouldn't have better notes surrounding using an EC2 instance. Maybe we could get them to update their tutorial?